# Anatomically Correct Yeti

Tags: biology, mountains, anatomically-correct, cryptids, primates

This is a submission for the Anatomically Correct Series.
[image: Wikipedia Yeti]
The Yeti/Abominable Snowman is a cryptid animal from British/Tibetan folklore. It is a large & bipedal apelike creature with white fur that lives in the Himalayan Mountains. It is also stated to have large, sharp teeth and primarily eats meat. The Yeti is often compared to Sasquatch of North America.

Gorillas are the real life example of large, bipedal apes with sharp teeth. Gorillas live in Africa though and are primarily herbivorous. What traits would a carnivorous gorilla-like creature need in order to survive in the Himalayas and be hidden from humans?

Comment: Downvotes without comment fix _nothing_, folks.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I think a yeti downvoted it.

Comment: @Starfish Prime I think some posters downvote and VTC Anatomically Correct Series questions out of principle. ACS use to be a major attraction for lurkers to sign up, but now it became a taboo subject due to low quality submissions and other controversies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentition is going to look most omnivorous but won't quite transform into proper carnivorous teeth. Less gut, just don't need 40ft worth of intestine for meat. It's unclear if a primate's nails can transform into something more claw-like, but certainly stronger and sharper.

Would be easier if we knew if this was an ambush predator or a chase predator. That should effect body shape to some extent... though even if it chases prey, I doubt we'd get upright sprinting. But persistence is less effective when you're on a cold mountain, you just can't chase an antelope until it overheats and can run no longer. Let's go with ambush then. On a mountain, it may well use the primate talent for climbing. In many places up on a mountainside, the prey might not have many escape options anyway. A yeti that climbs up from below or drops from above could have an easy meal.

This does affect its optimum size. This might not be a 10ft bigfoot. The less mass it has, the easier time it will have climbing. 200, 250 lbs maybe.

Given how we know yetis tend towards hiding, it might be nocturnal. Its eyes might be more like those of the known nocturnal primates. Could probably claim whichever color works for your story, but I expect night vision at least comparable to domestic cats, or perhaps more impressive still (not alot of light pollution in the Himalayas).

Heavily furred, able to shed most of that in spring if necessary. Fur color might be seasonal (but probably not at the altitudes we find it).

Unusual vascular mechanisms in the feet and hands to reduce heat loss and prevent frost bite. Higher RBC count. Lungs that eke out every little last scrap of oxygen. A large nose to deal with air temperature.

The easy thing would be to claim this is some undiscovered surviving holdout of a gigantopith lineage, but primate fossils are sparse enough that this could be an entirely new genus. I would be reluctant to believe that it could be extant in more than one location on planet Earth. You get the Himalayas, but no North American sasquatch. It's a critically endangered species after all, with a nearly unviable breeding population of just a few adult specimens. No more than a dozen, tops.

Comment: I suggest a big nose like the big nose monkey.

Answer (score 2):

## Snow Leopard

Your Sasquatch is essentially a snow leopard. Snow leopards live in the Himalayas. They are carnivores and since there is so little food up there, they need huge ranges. As a result they are extremely rare, well-hidden from humans and hard to film:

[image]

This is [BBC Planet Earth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uj0EVT-Ekog) from by the way. The first intimate film of wild snow leopards is from 2006.

Anyway, your Sasquatch is about 50kg big. A bit lighter than most human adults. The same weight as a big snow leopard. It has the same diet as a snow leopard, the same type of coat and behaviour.  It has big fangs for tearing flesh like a chimp:

[image]

It is more like a gibbon than a gorilla. After all, it needs to be super nimble climbing those slopes to catch wild goats.

[image]

Sasquatch is about 6 foot tall when he stands up tall. His puffy coat makes him look bigger. But he is deceptively light and graceful. And since he's so rarely seen, people think he's a big hulking monster. He's actually a lithe, lanky monster.

In fact most Sasquatch attacks are the Sasquatch pushing people down a slope, rather than battering them to a pulp. This does the job and leave loads of blood to enhance the legend.

Comment: Baboons can hunt an antelope when favorable conditions present themselves. They can be fierce in the fight, grabbers and jaws are a good combination. To cover long distances its locomotion might be more human like. The ape locomotion is practical in trees, but climbing mountains is different. Throwing rocks might be an advantageous trait in hunting or self defense.